# Run a script quickly from second time onward

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python script that takes a lot of time to complete.
The line that takes most of the time is:

```
ndf['embeddings'] = ndf['embeddings'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Is there any way to pickle the results so that I will have to wait only for the first time?

Comment: each record is a list of few thousand float values.

Comment: `.apply` is simply a convenience function... its basically the same as doing `embeddings = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in rows]` you lose all the speed ups ... to tell you how you might speed it up we would need to see what those entries that you are doing `ast.literal_eval` to look like

Comment: @Joran They're not asking how to speed it up, they're asking how to save it.

Comment: @wjandrea ... lol thats what i get for not reading it properly...

Comment: A dataframe has a `to_pickle` method.

Comment: DataFrame and Series have [`to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) methods, have you tried them? (I've never used them myself, but they seem like the logical choice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure

```
ndf.to_pickle("mydf.pkl")
```

should do just that

you can then load it with `pandas.read_pickle("mydf.pkl")`

Comment: Is reading from pickle file same as read_csv?

Comment: is it the same as `read_csv`? no... its `read_pickle` instead and takes some different arguments... but yes in the sense there is a `read_` method that makes loading it easy